# Camera still functions even view controller is changed

Tags: ios, camera, zxing

I integrated zxing to my app and in my app, I have two tabs. One is history and another one is scan . The problem is when I moved to history tab, the camera still scans whenever the camera is faced to a barcode . I have no idea how to suspend the camera when the view is changed.

This is what I have in my view did load for scan view controller.

```
 self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;

self.capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scanRectView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.decodedLabel];
```

could anyone tell me how to shutdown the camera once the view is changed?

Answer (score 1):

I called the following method to stop the camera function once the view is changed.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.view.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.view = nil;
    self.capture=nil;
    [self.capture.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

}

Now it works.